# Why would vector space addition axiom #5 be verified in this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, axioms

Given V = $\mathbb{R}$ with the following addition and scalar multiplication:
$$x+y = x+y+7$$
$$a \cdot x=ax+7(a-1)$$
where a $\in \mathbb{R}$, while proving that V is a vector space, how come the correct way to verify axiom #5* is as follows:
$$x+y=7$$
$$x+y+7=-7$$
$$x+y=-14$$
$$y=-14-x$$
and not:
$$x+y+7=0$$
$$y=-x-7$$

Since the axiom states that $u+(-u)=0$ then why would $x+y=7$ and not $x+y=0$

* Axiom #5 states that for each u in V, there exists another vector "-u" such that $u+(-u)=(-u)+u=0$

Comment: It seems to me that you might be confused over two usages of "$+$". There's the *definition of addition* in the vector space, and then there's *regular old addition* for real numbers. That's why you will often see an alternate symbol. Perhaps the first line should be:
$$x \oplus y = x + y +7$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use $\oplus$ for vector addition. The zero vector is $-7$, since for all $x$ we have

$$x \oplus -7 = x + (-7) + 7 = x.$$

So, to find the inverse of any $x$, we need a $y$ such that $x \oplus y = -7$:

$$x \oplus y = -7\\
x + y + 7 =-7\\
y = -x - 14$$

Without distinguishing $+$ from $\oplus$, this would get very confusing! How is it actually written in your notes (or textbook), I wonder?

Comment: Ohhh I see my error.  I had previously calculated the zero vector to be -7 as well, however I set u + (-2) to be 0 and not the zero vector which is -7.  Thanks!  Also, in both my notes and textbook it is written as + and not $\oplus$

Comment: Happy to help! In cases where the vector operations are non-standard and incorporate the regular operations over the reals, I strongly recommend using two different symbols to keep things straight. (There are other choices besides the one I used above, e.g., $\dotplus, \boxplus, +', \tilde +$. Pick your favourite one.)